# Generation exe file from perl script using active state perl 5.26

Tags: windows, perl, exe, activeperl, perlscript

I want to  convert my perl script to .exe using Active state perl 5.26 in windows 10.

I tried searching it but found it for older versions.

I can't find Par::paker for active perl 5.26. Is pp not supported for 5.26? What's the alternative for pp for 5.26 on windows 10

Comment: How did you try to install the module? Only via PPM or also via CPAN?

Comment: I tried installing with ppm. But the par packer  package is not found.

Comment: 64-bit version Igm guess? Them forget about PP. Use CPAN.

Comment: Please tell me  the command to generate .exe using cpan

Comment: CPAN for installing the module I meant. The command is `cpan`. Look in the documentation for the arguments and options.